# Is it possible to create same ear file in maven which is generated from ant in Ant to Maven migration?

Tags: maven, ant, migration, ear-file

I am trying to migrate enterprise application from ant to maven. Can we generate same kind of ear file in maven which is generated from ant?

Because ant ear file has different folders in it along with group of jar and war files.Few folders contains dependency jars and one of the folder has shell scripts. How to add this folders in maven project?

Comment: Yes of course there is a maven-ear-plugin which means you have to have a module which is packaging: ear which in result means having different modules (jar, war, and finally an ear)... shell scripts sounds wrong...

Comment: As example you can take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee